# fswatch does not pass arguments to xargs

Tags: macos, xargs

I'm starting using fswatch on os x. I've read [tutorial](http://emcrisostomo.github.io/fswatch/doc/1.6.0/html/fswatch/Tutorial-Introduction-to-fswatch.html#Processing-fswatch-Output), but example from there does not work for some reason.

I'm executing

`fswatch /$HOME/Projects/utils/configs/.vimrc | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} echo {}`

in terminal and at the same time I'm editing the file in another terminal. But nothing is outputted.

I've tried to run just

`fswatch /$HOME/Projects/utils/configs/.vimrc`

and it works perfectly, outputting the name of the file everytime I edit it.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `-0` flag to `fswatch`:

```
fswatch -0 $HOME/Projects/utils/configs/.vimrc | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} echo {}
```